# Remove char at specific index - python

Tags: python

I have a string that has two "0" (str) in it and I want to remove only the "0" (str) at index 4

I have tried calling .replace but obviously that removes all "0", and I cannot find a function that will remove the char at position 4 for me.

Anyone have a hint for me?

Comment: Noting top answers rely on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9490058/why-does-substring-slicing-with-index-out-of-range-work

Answer (score 110, accepted):

Use slicing, rebuilding the string minus the index you want to remove:

```
newstr = oldstr[:4] + oldstr[5:]
```

Answer (score 25):

as a sidenote, `replace` doesn't have to move all zeros. If you just want to remove the first specify `count` to 1:

```
'asd0asd0'.replace('0','',1)
```

Out:

`'asdasd0'`

Comment: What if you wanted to replace the `0` at index `7` only?

Answer (score 20):

This is my generic solution for any string  `s` and any index `i`:

```
def remove_at(i: int, s: str) -> str:
    return s[:i] + s[i+1:]
```

Comment: thanks for the contrib https://stackoverflow.com/users/752843/richard

Answer (score 7):

Another option, using list comprehension and join:

```
''.join([_str[i] for i in xrange(len(_str)) if i  != 4])
```

Comment: I like this one the best because it can be generalized... my problem was solved with `''.join([x for x in _str if x not in forbidden_chars])`

Answer (score 6):

Slicing works (and is the preferred approach), but just an alternative if more operations are needed (but then converting to a list wouldn't hurt anyway):

```
>>> a = '123456789'
>>> b = bytearray(a)
>>> del b[3]
>>> b
bytearray(b'12356789')
>>> str(b)
'12356789'
```

Answer (score 3):

```
rem = lambda x, unwanted : ''.join([ c for i, c in enumerate(x) if i != unwanted])
rem('1230004', 4)
'123004'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def remove_char(input_string, index):
    first_part = input_string[:index]
    second_part = input_string[index+1:]
    return first_part + second_part

s = 'aababc'
index = 1
remove_char(s,index)
```

zero-based indexing

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
s = input() 
a = int(input()) 
b = s.replace(s[a],'')
print(b)
```

Comment: This question is 5 years old :/ Also while this might answer the authors question, it lacks some explaining words and links to documentation. Raw code snippets are not very helpful without some phrases around it. Please edit your answer.

Comment: This will replace all occurrences of s[a].