# How could I remove a piece of string by its index?

Tags: python, string

I basically have a string:

`string = "Hello\nWorld\n"`

And I'm trying to remove only the last '\n'. I tried using:

`string.replace("\n", "")`

But it removes both '\n's. After that, I tried:

`string.replace(string[-1], "")`

Also removed both. How could I only remove the last one ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove char at specific index - python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14198497/remove-char-at-specific-index-python)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use strip to remove only newlines

```
>>> string = "Hello\nWorld\n"
>>> 
>>> string.strip()
'Hello\nWorld'
>>>
```

Comment: It will also remove spaces