# Slicing a string with user input

Tags: python

I need to take user input such as: `whacky` and `2` and the output needs to be `whky`

I understand you slice a string with

```
s[start:stop:skip]
```

but I am not sure how to achieve my goal.

Comment: `s[:2] + s[-2:]`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove char at specific index - python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14198497/remove-char-at-specific-index-python)

Answer (score 0):

```
s = input()
i = int(input())

print(s[:i] + s[-i:])
```