# Any value deleting in dataframe cell

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to transform dataset type. But i cant do it beacuse of there are two dot in my dataset. Im using `pd.apply(pd.to_numeric)` code. The error code I get is as follows;

```
ValueError: Unable to parse string "1.232.2" at position 1
```

my dataset is like this;

```
  Price     Value
 1.232.2   1.235.3
 2.345.2   1.234.2
 3.343.5   5.433.3
```

I must do removing first dot. Example for;

```
   Price     Value
 1232.2      1235.3
 2345.2      1234.2
 3343.5      5433.3
```

I waiting for help. Thank you.

Comment: What the value of `1.232.2` should be?

Comment: rest of the values only have 1 dot?

Comment: Remove the dot on the second index (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14198497/remove-char-at-specific-index-python) and use `.apply`). Then apply `.to_numeric`.

Comment: @QuangHoang value of 1.232.2 should be 1232.2

Comment: @SandrinJoy yes.

Comment: @Gego do you have more than two dots in your data? Or every cell have at most two dots?

Comment: This appears to be a trivial bit of string processing.  What is the problem?  Do you not know how to alter a string?  If so, repeat any tutorial on strings.  Do you not know how to identify DF rows, or to apply a transformation to the ones you find?  Those are both in any tutorial on Pandas.  If it's something else, please explain.

Comment: You should count # of . and if it has more than 1, then strip to have only last two parts joined with a . while stripping out the rest

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to do this.

## Convert string to float format (multiple dots to single dot)

You can just do a regex to solve for this.

regex expression: `'\.(?=.*\.)'`

Explanation:

`'\.` --> lookup for literal `.`

`(?=.*\.)'` --> Exclude all but last `.`

For each found, replace with `''`

The code for this is:

```
df['Price'] = df['Price'].str.replace('\.(?=.*\.)', '',regex=True)
df['Value'] = df['Value'].str.replace('\.(?=.*\.)', '',regex=True)
```

If you also want to convert it to numeric, you can directly give:

```
df['Price'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Price'].str.replace('\.(?=.*\.)', '',regex=True))
df['Value'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Value'].str.replace('\.(?=.*\.)', '',regex=True))
```

The output of this will be:

Before Cleansing DataFrame:

```
     Price     Value
0  1.232.2   1.235.3
1  2.345.2   1.234.2
2  3.343.5   5.433.3
3   123.45  456.25.5
4    0.825     0.0.0
5  0.0.0.2     5.5.5
6     1234      4567
7      NaN       NaN
```

After Cleansing DataFrame:

```
    Price    Value
0  1232.2   1235.3
1  2345.2   1234.2
2  3343.5   5433.3
3  123.45  45625.5
4   0.825     00.0
5   000.2     55.5
6    1234     4567
7     NaN      NaN
```

The pd.numeric() version of the solution will look like this:

After Cleanins DataFrame:

Note: it converts all values to 3 decimal places as one of them has 3 decimal places.

```
      Price    Value
0  1232.200   1235.3
1  2345.200   1234.2
2  3343.500   5433.3
3   123.450  45625.5
4     0.825      0.0
5     0.200     55.5
6  1234.000   4567.0
7       NaN      NaN
```

## Discard data if more than one period (.) in data

If you want to process all the columns in the dataframe, you can use `applymap()` and if you want to process for a specific column use apply. Also use `pd.isnull()` to check if data is `NaN` so you can ignore processing that data.

The below code addresses for NaN, numbers without decimal places, numbers with one period, numbers with multiple periods. The code assumes the data in the columns are either NaNs or strings with digits and periods. It assumes there are no alphabet or non digit characters (except dots). If you need the code to check for digits only, let me know.

The code also assumes that you want to discard the leading numbers. If you do want to concatenate the numbers, then a different solution needs to be implemented (for ex: `1.2345.67` will be replaced to `2345.67` and `1` will be discarded. example #2: `1.2.3.4.5` will be replaced with `4.5` while discarding `1.2.3`. If this is NOT what you want, we need to change the code.

You can do the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'Price': ['1.232.2', '2.345.2', '3.343.5', '123.45', '0.825','0.0.0.2', '1234',np.NaN],
                   'Value': ['1.235.3', '1.234.2', '5.433.3', '456.25.5','0.0.0','5.5.5', '4567',np.NaN]})

print (df)

def remove_dots(x):
    return x if pd.isnull(x) else '.'.join(x.rsplit('.',2)[-2:])

df = df.applymap(remove_dots)
print (df)
```

The output of this will be:

Before Cleansing DataFrame:

```
     Price     Value
0  1.232.2   1.235.3
1  2.345.2   1.234.2
2  3.343.5   5.433.3
3   123.45  456.25.5
4    0.825     0.0.0
5  0.0.0.2     5.5.5
6     1234      4567
7      NaN       NaN
```

After Cleansing DataFrame:

```
    Price  Value
0   232.2  235.3
1   345.2  234.2
2   343.5  433.3
3  123.45   25.5
4   0.825    0.0
5     0.2    5.5
6    1234   4567
7     NaN    NaN
```

If you want to change specific columns only, then you can use apply.

```
df['Price'] = df['Price'].apply(lambda x: x if pd.isnull(x) else '.'.join(x.rsplit('.',2)[-2:]))
df['Value'] = df['Value'].apply(lambda x: x if pd.isnull(x) else '.'.join(x.rsplit('.',2)[-2:]))

print(df)
```

Before and after will be the same:

Before Cleansing DataFrame:

```
     Price     Value
0  1.232.2   1.235.3
1  2.345.2   1.234.2
2  3.343.5   5.433.3
3   123.45  456.25.5
4    0.825     0.0.0
5  0.0.0.2     5.5.5
6     1234      4567
7      NaN       NaN
```

After Cleansing DataFrame:

```
    Price  Value
0   232.2  235.3
1   345.2  234.2
2   343.5  433.3
3  123.45   25.5
4   0.825    0.0
5     0.2    5.5
6    1234   4567
7     NaN    NaN
```

Comment: Thank you for helps.