# Elegant way to access last two and next two elements in a list?

Tags: python, list

I need to access the previous two and next two elements(if exist).
e.g. `[..., a, b, c, d, e, ..]` -> For `c` I want `abcde`.

This is easy for elements in the middle of a list, but in the beginning and end it will cause Index out of range errors. And if the list is smaller it becomes even more complicated.

I can do it with a bunch of `if`-`elif`-`elif`--`else` statements for all the cases, but is there any concise and elegant way to accomplish this?

I'm using python 2.7

Comment: are you accessing by element or passing an index?

Comment: Given `[0,1,2,3,4,5,6]` what result do you want for `1`?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham By index. I'll use it as `for index in range(0,len(list)):`

Comment: @georg I want [0,1,2,3]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use slicing (but be careful about negative indices):

```
inputlist[max(0, index - 2):index + 3]
```

will get you a window of up to 5 elements around `index`; 2 before and 2 after.

The `max()` call ensures that the start index is capped to `0` or up.

This'll work with whatever method you used to produce your index. Say you are using a loop, together with `enumerate()` to keep track of the index:

```
def window(inputlist, index):
    return inputlist[max(0, index - 2):index + 3]

for index, elem in enumerate(inputlist):
    print window(inputlist, index)
```

or you found your element with `list.index()`:

```
print window(inputlist, inputlist.index('ham'))
```

Demo:

```
>>> def window(inputlist, index):
...     return inputlist[max(0, index - 2):index + 3]
... 
>>> window(['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'spam', 'ham', 'eggs'], 1)
['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'spam']
>>> window(['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'spam', 'ham', 'eggs'], 2)
['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'spam', 'ham']
>>> window(['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'spam', 'ham', 'eggs'], 4)
['baz', 'spam', 'ham', 'eggs']
>>> window(['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'spam', 'ham', 'eggs'], 5)
['spam', 'ham', 'eggs']
```

Comment: This works, but how come the larger indices don't throw off errors? Because if I do it for the last element, I'll be trying to access elements with index larger than the length? e.g. for `input = [1,2,3]` and `index = 1` this simplifies to `input[0:4]`

Comment: @hoodakaushal: slicing *always* returns a result. That result can be empty, but there are no out-of-bounds indices when it comes to slicing.

Comment: @hoodakaushal: see [Why substring slicing index out of range works in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9490058)

Answer (score 2):

You want to [slice](http://www.pythoncentral.io/how-to-slice-listsarrays-and-tuples-in-python/) your list

```
l = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j']
print l[max(0, l.index('f') - 2):l.index('f') + 3]
['d', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h']
```

Something that you need to be aware of when slicing is negative indexes.

A few other examples:

```
print l[max(0, l.index('a') - 2):l.index('a') + 3]
['a', 'b', 'c']

print l[max(0, l.index('j') - 2):l.index('j') + 3]
['h', 'i', 'j']

print l[max(0, l.index('c') - 2):l.index('c') + 3]
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
```

Important note:

If you have duplicate values in your list, the `index()` function will utilize the first index the value is seen:

```
l = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','f']
print l[max(0, l.index('f') - 2):l.index('f') + 3]
['d', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h']
```

Notice that `f` appears twice. In this instance, it does not use the second index.

Comment: what if there are two f's?

Comment: A valid point. If there are duplicate values, it will utilize the first index that the value appears at.