# python substring does not seem to throw array index out of bound

Tags: python, substring

I am converting python code to java. It appears that when a python string is empty, a statement like this

```
mystring[-4:]
```

is perfectly fine. no exception occurs at all.

Is this right? I am from a java background. I just find this hard to believe.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9490058/why-substring-slicing-index-out-of-range-works-in-python

Comment: @rosshamish Flag as duplicate if you see striking resemblance amongst 2 questions.

Comment: Straight quote from the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#strings) *out of range slice indexes are handled gracefully when used for slicing* and do not result in Exceptions

Comment: @BhargavRao Thanks for the tip, I was actually wondering how to mark as duplicate, hadn't done it before. OP: The question I linked explains this pretty well, take a look.

Comment: thanks. takes some getting use to.