# Which exception should __getitem__/__setitem__ use with an unsupported slice step size?

Tags: python, exception, slice

I found this code in a 3rd party module which was ignoring `foo[::step]` or `key.step` in this case.

```
def __getitem__(self, key):
    if isinstance(key, slice):
        return self._sub_slice(key.start, key.stop)
    if self._is_in_range(key):
        return self._tree[key]
    else:
        raise KeyError(key)
```

While supporting steps would be ideal, assuming this isn't going to be supported, I'd like to add an exception, otherwise `foo[a:b:-1]` for eg will ignore the `-1` in the slice.

eg:

```
if key.step not in {None, 1}:
    raise Exception("only a step size of 1 is supported")
```

---

So my question is, for valid but unsupported slice steps,
which exception type should be used?

Comment: Note that an unsupplied step size defaults to `None`, not `1`.

Comment: I'd recommend making your own `SliceStepError` class; the built-in ones don't match very well.

Comment: Correct me if I'm misunderstanding, but slicing doesn't usually raise an exception. Accessing an index out of range will, but the slicing won't. Let me know if this is helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9490148/1832539

Answer (score 2):

> **ValueError**
>
> Raised when a built-in operation or function receives an argument that has *the right type but an inappropriate value*, and the situation is not described by a more precise exception such as [IndexError](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#IndexError).
>
> https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#ValueError

"The right type but an inappropriate value" seems to match your description pretty well.