# Empty string returned instead of IndexError

Tags: python, string, slice, index-error

I'm really confused now:

```
>>> string = "some string"
>>> string[100:105]
''
>>> string[100]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: string index out of range
```

Why does `string[100:105]` return an empty string whereas `string[100]` raises an IndexError (as expected)? Why does `string[100:105]` not raise an IndexError as well?

Comment: Because that's how it's defined. Slices will never raise index errors.

Comment: That's just the weird design decision they made.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9490058/why-substring-slicing-index-out-of-range-works-in-python. Flagged as duplicate

Answer (score 1):

When slicing a string in Python, the `string[100:105]`, the operation was designed specifically to fail gracefully.  The result of an out of range slice is to return the empty string ''.  See the [Informal Introduction](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html) for more information.

Accessing a specific index of a string, the `string[100]` was not designed to fail gracefully, so it raise an exception.

Answer (score 0):

String slicing in python will not raise errors, they will just return the string that you were looking for (in this case, it's indeed a empty string because there's nothing there).

Slicing returnes a subsequence of items, and it doesn't do any bound checking. If the wanted data (memory) is empty, it will send back an empty string as you got.