# Python compare two strings and check how many chars they have in common

Tags: python, string, char, compare

I'm just wondering how I can check how many chars two string have in common.
For example if I have "car" and "cars", the result should be 3.

Anybody a clue?

Cheers and thanks in advance

Max

Comment: like in any order or in specific spots, ie car, rac = 3 as well? what about repeats

Comment: Do you know how to [Iterate over a string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43605490/python-iterate-over-string)? That will let you go character by character.

Comment: Iterate though the first string, add 1 if you find the current character in the second string. Return result ?

Comment: @lPlant yes, car and rac should be 3 as well

Comment: I could answer this question with "Yes I have a clue." But I don't think that's the answer you're looking for. Try to make sure your question is meaningful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution using [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).  We make a `Counter` for each of the words, then find the intersection of those `Counter`s.  That itself is a `Counter`, and we can just sum the values to find the number of shared characters

```
from collections import Counter

def shared_chars(s1, s2):
    return sum((Counter(s1) & Counter(s2)).values())

print(shared_chars('car', 'carts'))
```

will print

```
3
```

In case of `Counter`, intersection is the minimum of corresponding counts.

```
>>> Counter('abbb') & Counter('bcc')
Counter({'b': 1})
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you didn't write any code, I won't either. But basically this:

-convert strings to list

-use set to get letters they have in common

-get length of your set

Biggest hazard here would be if you wanted to count repeating letters

Answer (score 1):

Something like this

```
count = 0

for letter in set(string1):
  count += string2.count(letter)

print(count)
```