# Slice operator in python

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x

```
>>> word="python"
>>> word[42]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: string index out of range
>>> word[4:42]
'on'
>>> word[42:]
''
```

My question is that why slice operator doesn't give `IndexError`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why substring slicing index out of range works in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9490058/why-substring-slicing-index-out-of-range-works-in-python)

Comment: You can find the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9490058/why-substring-slicing-index-out-of-range-works-in-python