# Start iteration from second element in Python

Tags: python

I have the next part of code in python:

```
for (script, location) in self.device.scripts:
```

How can I start to take elements from the second pair of the given list? 
And if that is possible where should I check if a second element exist?

Comment: consider using [python zip](https://medium.com/@happymishra66/zip-in-python-48cb4f70d013)

Answer (score 7):

Use `itertools.islice()` to slice skipping the first.

```
from itertools import islice
for (script, location) in islice(self.device.scripts, 1, None):
    pass # do stuff
```

Comment: It's a list, so why not just `self.device.scripts[1:]`

Comment: Both ideas worked. Thank you

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ: Why? because this works for the general case for any iterable and doesn't make a copy of the values (since it is a list), this just iterates.

Comment: Just saying; you don't need a monkey-wrench to hammer a nail.

Answer (score 7):

Just slice it.

```
for script, location in self.device.scripts[1:]:
    pass
```

For your second question, you don't need to worry about any `IndexError` since [slicing returns an empty list](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9490058/6622817) when it's out of range.