# Python: x = "p", why does x[:-2] return an empty string instead of "p"?

Tags: python, slice

I'm still very new to Python and confused by the question below.

below is the code:

```
x = "p"
y = x[:-2]
```

Why doesn't Python handle x[:-2] as an "out-of-bound" slicing and return "p"? In stead, it returns an empty string.

Thank you!

Comment: actually it should return **index out of range**, I tested it, and yes, strange output 

Comment: No @CYREX it shouldn't.  This behavior is consistent with how python treats slicing all built-in sequences. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9490058/why-does-substring-slicing-with-index-out-of-range-work

Comment: A simpler example that reproduces this: `'p'[:-2]` also gives ''

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Sorry, I misread the question as x[:-1]. I'm leaving my original answer because why not.

Let me break it down..
First, in python, a negative index is equivalent to saying [len(my_string) + i]. I being the negative number.
For example:

```
x="abcdefg"
y=x[-2]
print(y)
# will print "f"
```

Second, `x[:-1]` is shorthand for x[0:-1], so this would return the substring between the beginning and the last letter (**exclusive**)

So the reason that you get an empty string in the case of a string of length one is because x[:-1] is equivalent to x[0:0]