# Why does str[64:] work while str[64] doesn't?

Tags: python, string, indexing

Say you have a string named s:

```
s = "000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
len(s)
#63
```

When you run `s[64:]`, the Python compiler returns `''`.
However, when you run `s[64]` the code raises the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: string index out of range
```

Why does this happen?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sidenote, `str` is a bad name cause it shadows the builtin `str` type. You could use `s` or `string` instead. C.f. [TypeError: 'list' object is not callable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31087111/4518341)

Comment: Mostly, programmer convenience.  Most seemingly invalid slices return valid empty results, like `str[9:5]`.  Direct references to an element, on the other hand, are usually a programming error and should be caught.

Comment: For this string, the slice `64:` is an empty slice, which is not required to be anchored within the string.  `64` by itself, on the other hand attempts to reference a single element of the string that does not exist, which is an error.  Also, you should avoid using `str` as a variable name, since that will mask the default definition of `str`.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9490148/4518341) is my favourite answer to this question, and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42680568/4518341) is rigorous.