# How to allow the first element to be included in a reverse slice?

Tags: python, list, slice

I'm trying to figure out how to define a `slice` that's capable of returning the first element.

```py
>>> x = list(range(100))
>>> s = slice(91, 100, 2)
>>> x[s] 
[91, 93, 95, 97, 99]  # Highest works fine.

>>> s = slice(10, -1, -2)
>>> x[s]
[]  # Nope

>>> s = slice(10, 0, -2)
>>> x[s]
[10, 8, 6, 4, 2]  # No zero

>>> 0 in x
True
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'd have to use `None` here. You wanted `x[10::-2]` the slice equivalent would be:

```
s = slice(10, None, -2)
x[s]
# [10, 8, 6, 4, 2, 0]
```

Read this answer to fully understand how slicing in Python works: [Understanding slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation)

---

Let's say `slice(start, stop, step)` to explain why your other examples did not work

- `s = slice(10, 0, -2)` did not include `0` i.e first element because in slicing we take until `stop - 1`.
- `slice(10, -1, -2)` when using negative values slicing works in a different way. Negative values indicate values from the back of the list. So, the above slice would be `slice(10, len(x)-1, -2)`.
- `s = slice(91, 100, 2)` worked because `99`'s index is `99`(`x.index(99)` -> `99`) not `100`. `99` falls below `100` hence it's included.
- `slice(91, 9999, 2)` would give `[91, 93, 95, 97, 99]` as values greater than `len(x)` would be replaced with `len(x)`. More about it [Why does substring slicing with index out of range work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9490058/12416453)