# What is numpy doing when assigning values beyond the dimensions of the array?

Tags: python, numpy

What exactly is numpy doing when you assign values outside the bounds of the array? Does it pose a risk of overwriting some area of the memory currently used by something else?

In this example, it writes row 9 to all ones. I was hoping to use this to get around an edge case, but I can't find any documentation on this behavior on the numpy pages for assigning or broadcasting.

```
import numpy as np
x = np.zeros([10, 5])
x[9:11] = 1
```

Edit per "solved by this other question":
I understand what it is doing and how it works. The question that I still have is if there is any risk of memory corruption or if the non-existent slice indices are ignored when writing/assigning.

Comment: It's standard Python, not just Numpy: "out of range slice indexes are handled gracefully when used for slicing" https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html

Comment: But if I do that with a list, it extends it. 
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does substring slicing with index out of range work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9490058/why-does-substring-slicing-with-index-out-of-range-work)

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42680568/18470692) explains the logic well.

Comment: @ChrisMcL yes, and that is what happens with the numpy array

Comment: and no, there isn't any risk of memory corruption. It's very important to understand, you aren't dealing with a primitive buffer here. You are *calling methods on a Python object*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the numpy docs [Slicing and striding](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#slicing-and-striding)

> You may use slicing to set values in the array, but (unlike lists) you
> can never grow the array. The size of the value to be set in x[obj] =
> value must be (broadcastable to) the same shape as x[obj].

When indexing, numpy strives for symmetry between getting and setting values. If a slice overflows a list when you get a value, it is not considered and error:

```
>>> l = [1,2,3]
>>> l[1:99]
[2, 3]
```

Similarly, when you assign a slice, numpy drops anything that would overflow. With `x[9:11] = 1`, numpy selected the single row that does not overflow the underlying buffer and broadcast a `1`. Numpy reduces the range for assignment and there is no overflow. In your case, you wanted to assign 2 rows but numpy modified your assignment and only set 1 row.

One could argue whether that is a good thing. But if you are concerned about overflowing operations, you need to check the dimensions yourself.

Comment: Yes, I get what it's doing. I'm curious if the overflow is dangerous and could overwrite something else in memory. Or is it only trying to write to the valid portion of the slice?

Comment: @ChrisMcL numpy/python != C/C++. The details of memory management are *internal* to `numpy.ndarray`. You are calling a method on an array object, and you have to trust that the people who implemented `np.ndarray` are handling memory correctly underneath the hood

Comment: @ChrisMcL there is no overflow. Numpy ignored the request to write rows outside of its array. Numpy always checks bounds. If it were to write outside of the lines, that would be a serious bug.